# Why PN junction can not be formed just by touching a P and a N type material?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronics

From school days we learnt that we can not form a PN junction just by touching a P and N type material. The reason provided is, there is much gap at contact for electron/hole to leave the N/P material and to diffuse to other at the junction. It seems acceptable unless we ask if same should happen in Metals too. When two metals are connected then electrons can flow very smoothly from one to another. Here also one can say that
' there is a huge gap compared to the lattice dimensions so electrons can not pass from one to another' but that is not true as we all know. Why same arguement does not work for both? Or is there any other arguement that can be said?

Comment: Electrons are fickle.  They don't care what atoms they use.  Doping introduces impurities to create extra hole and electrons.  Less atoms to use instead of 100%.

Comment: Just touching two pieces of metal together makes a really bad contact. 'Smooth flow' requires real contact, be it welding, soldering, etc.

Comment: Johannson Blocks  FTW  :-)   (at the theoretical limit of atomic smoothness.  As described in Foundation and Empire IIRC)